# external JS does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $.fn.dataTableExt.oPagination.input = {
        "fnInit": function (oSettings, nPaging, fnCallbackDraw) {
....
        },


        "fnUpdate": function (oSettings, fnCallbackDraw) {
....
        }
    };
</script>
```

and it works, but when I create external file and put this code inside this file (of course without `<script></script>` ) - it does not work. Why?

Comment: @Daedalus I tried. There is no such way to contact a user. And am not spewing hate. I love SO and I want to contribute too.

Comment: @Krishna I checked his 'user page', there is indeed a way to contact him.  Check his website.

Comment: @Daedalus. Thank you. I will check that. Please dont get me wrong. I want to be as helpful to my fellow developers as I can.

Answer (score 1):

just make sure the jQuery is the first script you load

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"><scrip>
<script type="text/javascript" src="yourScript.js"><script>
```